# Remove input tags field with elasticsearch and logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash-configuration, logstash-jdbc

I'm using logstash to send to elasticsearch, would someone know how to remove the [tags] field?
I am using this field to filter where each jdbc input should enter, I leave an example below.
What I would like is for that field not to be inserted into elasticsearch, I've tried remove_field but when using it, it doesn't directly insert into elastic.

```
    input {
      jdbc {
            jdbc_driver_library => "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/jars/ifxjdbc-4.50.3.jar"
            jdbc_driver_class => "com.informix.jdbc.IfxDriver"
            jdbc_connection_string => "zzzz"
            jdbc_user => "zzz"
            jdbc_password => "zzz"
            schedule => "*/5 * * * * *"                       
            statement => "SELECT * FROM informix.test ORDER BY tes_id ASC"
            tags => "test_001"
      }
    }

    filter { 
      mutate {
          remove_field => [ "@version","@timestamp" ]
      }
    } 
output {

  if "test_001" in [tags] {

        # Para ELK
        elasticsearch {
              hosts => "localhost:9200"
              index => "test"
              document_type => "test"
        }
  }      
}
```

Try doing it like this:

```
mutate { add_field => { "[@metadata][mitags]" => [tags]  }
           remove_field => [tags]
        }
```

But it doesn't insert in elasticsearch.

apparently the input [tags] in elasticsearch is created as an array ....

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use a field to filter on your output, you can't remove this field, it will be inserted in elasticsearch, unless you use the [`metadata`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/event-dependent-configuration.html#metadata) field, as it seems you were already trying, but the `add_field` config was wrong.

Try the pipeline below.

```
input {
  jdbc {
      ... your jdbc config ...
    tags => "test_001"
  }
}
filter { 
    mutate {
        add_field => { "[@metadata][tags]" => "%{tags}" } 
    }
    mutate {
        remove_field => ["@version","@timestamp","tags"]
    }
} 
output {
    if "test_001" in [@metadata][tags] {
        elasticsearch {
            ... your elasticsearch output ...
        }
    }      
}
```

The first mutate will add your tags in the field `[@metadata][tags]`, the second one will remove your fields, including the `tags`, then you can filter based on the `[@metadata][tags]`

Comment: Could you clarify the difference between% {field}, [field] and ["field"]? because I thought it worked the same way ...

Comment: You use `[field]` when you want to refer to a field to add a value or use it in a conditional, you use `%{field}` when you want to refer to the value of the field, when copying or adding a new field, `["field"]` is just an array with fields, this is how you use in some filters. For a better explanation lookt at this page in the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/event-dependent-configuration.html)